# Do I need Sign capability on my PGP master key

Tags: gpg, pgp

When generating a PGP master key, its capabilities default to Certificate and Sign (SC).
However, if I am going to create a signing sub key later and strip the master key to offline storage. Is it still good practice to allow the master key to carry the Sign capability? If so, why?

So instead of this

```
sec#  ed25519/0x0294CE5C 2021-06-09 [SC]
      F7062EDE4873F1290ED2B6FF8DAB03870294CE5C
uid           [ultimate] test@test.com
ssb   ed25519/0xF30B4B96 2021-06-09 [S]
```

I could have this

```
sec#  ed25519/0x0294CE5C 2021-06-09 [C]
      F7062EDE4873F1290ED2B6FF8DAB03870294CE5C
uid           [ultimate] test@test.com
ssb   ed25519/0xF30B4B96 2021-06-09 [S]
```

**Edit:** I found [this thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32386) on SO infosec which discussed the same scenario. In the end, for me the takeaway was that it may be a good practice to use the master key signing capabilities to enforce web of trust  *(i.e: signing other users keys)*, while using your subkey for trivial activities like signing emails, commits, etc. This was just my impression, though.

Answer (score 3):

All that is required of the primary key is the Certify ability. By default the primary key has Sign/Certify capabilities, but it is perfectly alright to have the primary key only certify subkeys that are used for signing and encryption.

You can remove the Sign capability from the primary key in the `edit-key` menu by using the command `change-usage` and then enter `S` to toggle the Sign capability off/on until it displays only "Certify" as the "Current allowed actions". Enter `Q` when finished then enter `save` to save the changes.